# Student here, Problem While loop doesn't work

Tags: java, loops

**Help me, While loop doesn't work, Sorry if my English is not good.

So basically this system works like if you choose the right answer it will run smoothly but my problem is when my try catch detected that I inserted some other choice like Symbols, the catch will say invalid answer and it will loop back to the question. I hope this makes sense.**

```
import java.util.*;
public class LabExer5B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean loop = true;            
        while(loop) {
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                String[] answerkey = {"b"};
                int correct = 0;
                String answer = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter your answers.\n");
                    answer = sc.next("b");
                    if (answer.compareTo(answerkey[0]) == 0) {
                        correct++;
                    }

                    System.out.println("You got " + correct + " out of 10");
                }

            } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Answer");
                loop = false;
            }

        }
   }       
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, stating your code "doesn't work" is not enough information. You need to describe what the desired behavior is along with what the actual problem is. In other words, what does your code do and how is that different from what it's supposed to do? See [ask] for more about asking questions. To improve your question click the [edit] link.

Comment: Please explain *what* doesn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what does not work?

Comment: Your request still is rather hard to understand. Could you perhaps try to explain *what you expect* the should do, if it ran properly?

Comment: Small hint: Try to fix your indentation first (for example how this is done properly, can be found at https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse142/12au/handouts/style-nick.pdf). This may also help you finding your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you put the correct answer in `sc.next()`.

Change this line

```
answer = sc.next("b");
```

to just this

```
answer = sc.next();
```

And that particular problem disappears.

Comment: @BaitChan no problem. Come back if you need more help.

Comment: Of course!!! :)

Comment: excuse me sir but when it loops it says Please enter your answer not Invalid asnwer.

Comment: @BaitChan when should it say invalid answer instead of looping?

Comment: when it activates the catch it should say invalid answer then loop.

Comment: Then remove this line:    'loop = false;'

Comment: it loops none stop xD

Comment: @BaitChan ah yes, you need an if statement in there to break the loop after it asks 10 questions.

Comment: @BaitChan I would encourage you to take the code over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Your program has a bunch of issues. I only addressed the main one in my answer. Also, post the assignment so we have a better idea of what you need.

Comment: I don't want to waste your time for me i am sorry xD

Comment: @BaitChan no, lol, it is not a problem. It is just that my ability to help you with code in the comments is limited.

Comment: I can only write so much in them.

Comment: @BaitChan or you can just post a new question on stack overflow listing these issues and tell us what your assignment is.

Comment: i can't keep up with this my brain can't handle it  xD i might just copy my classmate work xD